# Mapbox gl filters from a geojson external file

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl

How can I replace in this example the mapbox url with an external geojson file?
 https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/

```
        //'type': 'vector',
        //'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.04w69w5j'
        'type': 'geojson',
        'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.04w69w5j'
    });
```

and be able to filter it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

To use an external geojson file, in 'map.addSource' you need to replace 'url' with 'data'.

```
'type': 'geojson'
'data': 'yourfile.geojson'
```

Then in 'map.addLayer' remove the line

```
'source-layer': 'ne_10m_airports',
```